# Error: this.props.header is not a function when using StackNavigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-props, stack-navigator

I have a screen inside my react-navigation StackNavigator that looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { FlatList, ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { List, ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';
import Accordion from '@ercpereda/react-native-accordion';

export default class PassportScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Passport Recovery',
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.renderItem = this.renderItem.bind(this);
    }

    renderItem(item) {
        return (
            <View>
                <Accordion
                    header={item.item.key}
                    content={item.item.content}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }

    render() {
        const instructions = [
            {
                key: <Text>1. Fill out a passport application form</Text>,
                content: <Text>Content</Text>
            },
            {
                key: <Text>2. Fill out a lost/missing passport statement</Text>,
                content: <Text>Content</Text>
            },
            ///...etc
        ];

        return (
            <ScrollView>
                <FlatList
                    data={instructions}
                    renderItem={this.renderItem}
                />
            </ScrollView>
        )
    }
}

module.exports = PassportScreen;
```

however, when I click to navigate to this screen from another screen, I get this error: `TypeError: this.props.header is not a function. (In 'this.props.header({
              isOpen: this.state.is_visible
            })', 'this.props.header' is an instance of Object)`.
Other questions I've looked at with similar errors have mentioned passing props to the constructor and needing to pass `this.renderItem` instead of `this.renderItem()`, both of which I have already done, so I'm wondering if the problem comes from the fact that this screen is inside a StackNavigator and is navigated to by clicking on a ListItem. Is my intuition correct? If so, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the header prop accepts a function, rather than just a component like content does.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're directly passing an `object` to the header `prop`, therefore it won't accept the callback function.

You may try the following approach in order to pass a callback to the header.

**PassportScreen.js**

```
customFunc = (callback) => {
  console.log(callback)
}

renderItem = (item) => { // Useful to bind `this` 
        return (
            <View>
                <Accordion
                    header={this.customFunc}
                    content={item.item.content}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
```

**ChildComponent.js**

```
this.props.header('I'm setting the callback here')
```